# How to perform HTTP PUT Request by reading values from CSV in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, json, csv-file, http

I have a question how can I set up HTTP Request Sampler for HTTP PUT method in JMeter so it can read data from CSV file using CSV Data Set Config?
In my scenario I'm using **Concurrency Thread Group** with the following parameters:
* **Target Concurrency**: 50
* RampUp **Time** (**secs**): 10
* RampUp Steps **count**: 5
* Hold Target..(**secs**): 10

This is my **CSV Data Set Config** setup:
[image]

(Java) Types of **Variable Names** are:
bookId:**Long**, title:**String**, price:**double**, amount:**int**, authors: **Set** , categories: **Set** , isDeleted:**boolean**

This is my **HTTP Request Sampler** setup:[image]

...and this is **content** of my *bookCollection10Items.csv* file where **quoted values** are Strings, and the ones in angle brackets **[]** are **arrays**
of values (as I'm updating Book that has Many-To-Many relationship with Categories/Authors):

1,"Harry Potter and Magic Stone",39.99,2500,[4],7,11,false
2,"Murder on the Orient Express",[19.98,500500],1,9,false
3,"The Murder of Roger Ackroyd",19.99,1500,1,[7,9],false
4,"Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets",24.99,0,4,[7,9],true
5,"Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban",17.99,1200,4,7,false
6,"The Da Vinci Code",29.99,700,8,10,false
7,"Inferno",22.50,950,8,10,false
11,"War and Peace",31.99,300,5,8,false
14,"The Trial",27.99,450,6,9,false
15,"IT",16.50,0,2,5,true

What I want to achieve is that **each Thread(i.e. User)** to select **one item from** "bookCollection10Items.csv" file in a round-robin fashion and update it for a given bookId using "All Threads" as **Sharing Mode** option.
Any advice/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter's built-in CSV Data Set Config is reading lines from the CSV file **sequentially** so each user will get the next line on each iteration.

If you need to read a random line (however I don't think it's a good idea as I believe tests need to be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability)) you will need to go for some plugins like:

1. [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-random-csv-data-set-config-plugin-on-jmeter)
2. or [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/)

Both can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find a solution with my problem -> I made a mistake by:
**1)** Creating CSV file in **gEdit** (Linuxs' equivalent of Windows Notepad) instead of using LibreOffice Calc where work is done in **cells**. Therefore this way (both in *gEdit* and *LibreOffice Calc*):

> 3,"The Murder of Roger Ackroyd",19.99,1500,1,[7,9],false

...is a no-no.

**2)** Removing angle brackets **[]** from listing so arrays would NOT contain arrays. E.g. When angle brackets are present I get this:

```
{
   // some other fields
   "authors" : [[7,9]]
}
```

**3)** Had to properly format numbers with decimals to contain **dot**, NOT comma (**locale** issues). E.g. Proper format is 19.99, wrong format 19,99